# How to use multiple partials with Swig?

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

Swig doesn't render some partials in my view. How to pass `block`s the right way? What file should extend what?

I have such a structure of my view:

```
// files
header.html   // <- partial
header_logo.html   // <- partial
layout.html   // <- layout
index.html   // <- page
```

**index.html** is the one that Swig renders. It looks like this:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% extends 'header.html' %}
{% extends 'header_logo.html' %}

{% block head %}
    {% parent %}
    <link href="/assets/css/index/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

     {% block header_logo %}{% endblock %} // <- This one doesn't render

     .... html content code goes here ....
{% endblock %}
```

**layout.html** looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% block head %}
        <link href="/assets/css/index/layout.css" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>

    {% block header %}{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}  

  </body>
</html>
```

**header.html** looks like this:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block header %}
    ... html code goes here ...
{% endblock %}
```

**header_logo.html** looks like this. And this one doesn't render.

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block header_logo %}
    ... html code goes here ...
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only extend *one* template per file. What you want to do is something like this...

- `index.html` extends `header_logo.html`
- `header_logo.html` extends `header.html`
- `header.html` extends `layout.html`

Or, it looks like you want to *include* `header_logo` in your `index.html` template, not extend from it. You might be better off doing something like this...

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block header %}{% include 'header.html' %}{% end block %}
{% block content %}
    {% include 'header_logo.html' %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I dont't reckon this would work, say, for both a header AND a footer. Could you show us how your solution could work for cases when we have to do that for more than one block?

Answer (score 0):

#### Using a folder under the views folder (ExpressJS)

I created a partials folder under the views folder.

Then referenced the partial view like this from the reports.swig template.

```
{% extends 'layout.swig' %}

  {% block content %}

    {% for report in reports %}
      {% include './partials/displayReports.swig' %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks Paul for the answer!